# select month date from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to select distinct value and give me the number of values.

I want to select only the value in this month.

Example : give me all value of month 06 only in the same way distinct value number only in the month 06 or 05

***Remarque: the date type in the database is varchar not date.***

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select db_shopname, COUNT(db_shopname) as num FROM
(select tbl_order.db_shopname from tbl_order union all select tbl_item.db_shopname from tbl_item)t
GROUP BY db_shopname ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){       
    echo $res['db_shopname'];echo"&nbsp;";echo"(";echo $res['num'];echo")";echo"<br/>";
}
```

Comment: What does your existing code produce?  What does it produce if you just use MySQL rather than going through PHP?  How is it different from what you want?

Comment: this code produce if i have in t1 a a a b and in t2 a b c the result will be a(4) b(2) c(1) i want to add to this code to select only where the month date = to the month date of pc

Comment: OK, I get what it produces now; I'll assume that a, b, and c are db_shopnames.  a, b, and c aren't months; where do months come into this?  Is there a field in your database that relates to months in some way?

Comment: yes each value have a date

Comment: Would you care to tell us what that field is?  Don't hold back:  tell us everything!

Comment: db_date has date value for each value

Comment: add it into where condition WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`db_date `,'%Y/%m%d')) = MONTH(NOW())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull the month out of the varchar field use:

```
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(db_date ,'%Y/%m%d'))=MONTH(NOW())
```

Add this into `where` condition

EDIT:

I don't know its work for what you expecting but try it .

```
    select db_shopname, COUNT(db_shopname) as num 
    FROM
    (select tbl_order.db_shopname 
    from 
    tbl_order 
    where MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`db_date` ,'%Y/%m%d'))=MONTH(NOW())
    union 
    all 
    select tbl_item.db_shopname 
    from tbl_item
    where MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`db_date` ,'%Y/%m%d'))=MONTH(NOW()))t
    GROUP BY db_shopname
```

Comment: can you please add this code to my code because i add it and it didn't give me the result

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: run the mysql query into server or phpmyadmin  whatever your using

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result  this the msg

Comment: so no problem in query

Comment: can you tell your db_date column value stored structure 22/06/2016 or 2016/06/22  which one ?

Comment: 21/06/2016 this is  and item with month is 06

Comment: MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`db_date` ,'%d/%m/%Y'))   change like this  '%d/%m/%Y'

Answer (score 0):

hi if you want to convert date varchar to date for searching you can use below example

```
select date_format(str_to_date('31/12/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') - return 2010-12-31
```

If you want only year

```
select date_format(str_to_date('31/12/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y') - return 2010
```

If you want only month

```
select date_format(str_to_date('31/12/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m') - return 12
```

If you want only day

```
select date_format(str_to_date('31/12/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d') - return 31
```

Example

```
select count(name) from test where MONTH(str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = 06 group by name
```

Comment: i don't want to to convert i want to add to mysql a code to select distinct value with number of value for each month example if t1 (a,06/06/2016),(a,04/06/2016),(b,08/06/2016)  t2 (a,09/06/2016),b(02/05/2016) the result will be a (3) b(1)   ---> b is one not two because in t2 the month is not 06 is 05

Comment: select db_shopname, COUNT(db_shopname) as num FROM
(select tbl_order.db_shopname from tbl_order union all select tbl_item.db_shopname from tbl_item )t WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(db_date ,'%Y/%m%d')) = MONTH(NOW())               i add it to my query but didn' work